# Adding relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have loaded the below mailer.csv file to neo4j using the below command and am able to see all the 10 nodes .

CSV:

```
SENDER|RECEIVER|SENDDATE
Chris|Dean|2016-01-03
Brian|Chris|2016-01-02
Mark|Noah|2016-01-09
George|Henry|2016-01-05
Albert|Brian|2016-01-01
Thomas|Sean|2016-01-07
Sean|Mark|2016-01-08
Edgar|George|2016-01-04
Noah|Olivia|2016-01-10
Henry|Thomas|2016-01-06
```

Command:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:\\Users\\Abacus\\mailer.csv" AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (:Mailer {Sender: row.SENDER, Receiver: row.RECEIVER,Senddate:row.SENDDATE});


//select all nodes
MATCH (n:Mailer)
RETURN n;

//count of nodes

MATCH (n:Mailer)
RETURN count(*)
```

am trying to create the below relationship between senders and receivers to see the trail of mails

```
//create relationship
MATCH (n:Mailer)
CREATE (Sender)-[r:SENT_TO]->(Receiver);
```

But am unable to see the graphs in the below manner. Could you please help

```
send to     send to     send to
```

Albert------------Brian---------Chris-------------Dean

```
    send to         send to       send to       send to        send to     send to     send to
```

Edgar-------------George-------Henry--------------Thomas-----------Sean--------Mark-------Noah----------Olivia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. The sender and receiver are both turned into `Person` nodes, and each person's node is created just once.

```
MATCH (n:Mailer)
MERGE (p1:Person {name: n.Sender})
MERGE (p2:Person {name: n.Receiver})
CREATE (p1)-[r:SENT_TO {date:n.Senddate}]->(p2);
RETURN p1, r, p2;
```